# Use custom button as parent in custom style

Tags: android, android-styles

In my project I use special fonts for my buttons. So I've added the [PixlUI](https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI) library so I can set the font in xml.

```
<com.neopixl.pixlui.components.button.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            style="@style/custom_button_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/login"
            pixlui:typeface="AvenirNextCondensed-Regular.ttf" />


        <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.button.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            style="@style/custom_button_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/make_new_profile"
            pixlui:typeface="AvenirNextCondensed-Regular.ttf" />


        <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.button.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_broker_register"
            style="@style/custom_button_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/make_new_profile_broker"
            pixlui:typeface="AvenirNextCondensed-Regular.ttf" />
```

These are my buttons, since they all have the same typeface I want to include the typeface in the 'custom_button_style'

This my custom style:

```
<style name="custom_button_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/hello_medium_fontsize</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_btn_background</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/login_button_margin</item>
</style>
```

How do I include

> pixlui:typeface

in this style?

Comment: Does  `<item name="pixlui:typeface">AvenirNextCondensed-Regular.ttf</item>` works ?

Comment: No, I get an error 'No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'pixlui:typeface'. Do I have to change the Parent?

Comment: have You set this attribute to Your parent Layout?: xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui". Usualy, then YOu can use the pixlui attributes

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I have set that attribute to my parent layout, and I have no problems with using that attribute in my layout. 
But I want to include that attribute in my style to avoid having to include it with each button.

Comment: any luck on this one?

Answer (score -1):

It´s not clear if we can´t see the complete xml layout file, but things that often happens is that the poeple forget to add the xmlns attribute to the parent. You parent layout should look something like this. It´s part of this library and the important thing is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui" <----thats the important attribute
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
```

You don´t need to add something in Your style.xml. So if this does not fix Your problem, come back.

### EDIT

It is not tested yet, but for the style it could be:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <resources xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui">
     <style "custom_button_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/hello_medium_fontsize</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_btn_background</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/login_button_margin</item>
    <item name="pixlui:typeface">AvenirNextCondensed-Regular.ttf</item> 
 </style>
```